# Hidden Loading with UDK

Tags: udk, loading

I was wondering, how would I go about creating hidden loading scenes with UDK? For example, a character walks in to an elevator, the elevator fakes movement, whilst the previous floor is destroyed and the next floor is loaded on top.

I assume it's possible with UDK, since it's supposedly rather flexible, but I've never used UDK before (I decided to ask this question first to save me learning it all, finding out it isn't possible, then giving up).

So yeah, is hiding the loading process possible? And if so, how would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few relevant resources on the UDN about this subject (keywords "level streaming"), and even a convenient "hub" article that links to all of them:

http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/LevelStreamingHome.html

"The level streaming functionality in Unreal Engine 3 makes it possible to load and unload map files into memory as well as toggle their visibility all during play. This makes it possible to have worlds broken up into smaller chunks so that only the relevant parts of the world are taking up resources and being rendered at any point. If done properly, this allows for the creation of very large, seamless levels that can make the player feel as if they are playing within a world that dwarfs them in size."

Comment: Ah! Perfect! Thank you! "Level streaming" is a new term for me, I always wondered what it was called. Thanks so much!